# Angular 5: Hiding elements (if user isn't authenticated) not working

Tags: angular, express, passport.js, angular5, passport-local

this is app.component.html

```
<nav class='navbar navbar-default'>
<div class='container-fluid'>
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="" ></a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-left'>
    <li><a *ngIf="loggedin" routerLink="/posts">Posts</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="/profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a *ngIf="loggedin" routerLink="/settings">Settings</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="/register">Register</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="/login">Login</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="/administration">Administration</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

authentication.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {User} from "../../interfaces/user.interface";

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
logging: boolean = false;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

isloggedin() {
this.http.get('/loggedin')
  .toPromise()
  .then((data: any) => {
    console.log('data', data);
    if (data) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }

  });
 }

}
```

app.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {AuthenticationService} from 
"../../services/authentication/authentication.service";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
 })
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
title = 'twittscheR';
loggedin: any;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
 this.loggedin = AuthenticationService.isloggedin();
}
ngOnInit(){
 this.loggedin = this.isloggedin();
}
isloggedin() {
 return this.http.get('/loggedin');
}
}
```

I'm really new to Angular 5. How can I implement, that some elements in the navbar are only visible, if loggedin is true? Even the page is reloaded. Login functionality is working, but ngIf does not update the variable in navbar

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an varibale `loggedin` of type `BehaviorSubject<boolean>` in your `authentication.service.ts`:

```
loggedin: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);
```

Now modife your `isLoggedIn()`-function so, that if you get data then set `loggedin` to `true`, if no data then set it to `false`;

```
isloggedin() {
this.http.get('/loggedin')
  .toPromise()
  .then((data: any) => {
    console.log('data', data);
    if (data) {
      // login success
      this.loggedid.next(true);
    } else {
      // login fails
      this.loggedid.next(false);
    }

  });
 }
```

Now you can subscribe to `loggedin` varibale in your component. For that you should inject your authentication.service in app.component.ts.

```
loggedin: boolean;

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private authService: AuthenticationService) {
 this.authService.loggedin.subscribe(v => this.loggedin = v);
}
```

Now you can use `loggedin` variable from app.component.ts in your app.component.html.

Beware: For bring this solution to work, you should run your `isLoggedIn()` function e.g. by clicking on login button.

If you need more explanation, then let me know and I write larger tutorial.